# Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab

I just want to make some predictions using these calculations but I'm getting this error: Error using  *  Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in the second matrix. To operate on each element of the matrix individually, use TIMES (.*) for elementwise multiplication.

Error in main (line 64) r=(pn')*(best);

[the dataset](https://codeshare.io/AdVpgv)

Main driver

```
clear; clc;
%load dataset

ds = load('ex1data1.txt');

%split x/y



x = ds(:,1); % Examples
y = ds(:,2);
n=1;
m=length(y);
format long;
b1 = x\y;  %intercept
    
    %plot lineer regression 
    % Top plot
yCalc1 = b1*x;
ax1 = nexttile;
scatter(ax1,x,y,'o');
hold on
plot(ax1,x,yCalc1);
title(ax1,'Linear Regression Relation Between Profit & Truck')
ax1.FontSize = 14;
ax1.XColor = 'red';
ylabel('profit of a food truck');
xlabel('population of a city');
grid on



%normalise
[x,maxs,mins]=normalize(x);


%add column with ones - help hyphothesizs
xo=[ones(m,1),x];

%gradient descent
repeat=1500;
lrate=0.01;
thetas=zeros(2,1);
[best,costs] = gradientDescent(repeat,lrate,thetas,xo,y,m);


% plot () vs iteration


ax2 = nexttile;
scatter(ax2,costs,1:repeat)
title(ax2,' () vs iteration')
grid(ax2,'on')
ylabel('Iteration');
xlabel('J()');


%prediction


p=[7;7];
pn=(p-maxs')./(maxs'-mins');
pn = [1;pn];
r=(pn')*(best);
```

Gradient Descent

```
function [thetas,costs] = gradientDescent(repeat,lrate,thetas,xo,y,m)
    costs = zeros(repeat,1);
    for r = 1:repeat
        hc=xo*thetas - y;
        tempintercept=sum(hc.*xo);
        thetas = thetas - (lrate * (1/m)) * tempintercept';
        costs(r)=cost(thetas,xo,y);
    end
end
```

Normalize

```
function [x,maxs,mins] = normalize (x)
    
    x=(x-max(x))./(max(x)/min(x));
    maxs=max(x);
    mins=min(x);
end
```

Comment: What more is there to say? Your best is 2×1 and your pn is 3x1.

Comment: That error message is very clear. What is your question? See [ask].